# Producing prototypes from paper to HTML

Tags: user-interface, wireframing

I am in the beginning of this very interesting project and we decided to include mock-ups in the design part of the unified process of our lifecycle.

I am using different software to build my mockups:

1. **Balsamic** to produce a sort of paper mock-up
2. **Bootstrap** and **Photoshop** to produce real real-life content mock-ups

I would like to know if there is software out here that helps me draw my mock-up website and then generate an interactive interface?

It can be a web app or a local program for Windows.

Comment: As you tagged your question with [tag:web-apps], you are not interested in local solutions? Otherwise, which operating system(s)?

Comment: Yes I am interested in web application as well, I am currently working on the windows operating system. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In balsamiq you can link mockup together. That allow you to do interactive presentation. Here is the link to the how to:
http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/111742

I run across the following site that presents different mockup tools:

http://blog.profitbricks.com/top-29-mockup-and-wireframing-tools-for-developers/

And `lumzy` seems to have the prototyping capability you are looking for.

http://www.lumzy.com/

Comment: Thank you that is really useful, but there is any other software I can use?

Comment: @JeanWilliamEyidi: Please explain what is wrong with the software listed in this answer.

Comment: sure, the reason is that it doesn't produce HTML from the prototype, but the rest seems to be pretty much what I was looking for thanks.